# ArcGIS python script to replace dates in a geodatabase table date field

Tags: python, arcgis

I am trying to update a date field in a geodatabase table using field calculator, so that all dates before 01/01/2001 are replaced with 01/01/2001 while leaving other dates unchanged.  As the date field is in a geodatabase it also has a time stamp (format: yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss). Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Use `datetime` (https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html) for this. The following snippet shows how to convert your strings to `datetime.datetime` objects and use those to compare the dates. Depending on your database you can try to vectorize this.

```
import datetime                                                                   

def convert(string):                                                              
    dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(string, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")                  
    return dt                                                                     

example_before = convert("1999-03-22 11:32:53")                                        
thresh = convert("2001-01-01 00:00:00")                                           

# use < and > to compare dates works with datetime!                                        
if example_before < thresh:                                                       
    print("Yes")                                                                  
    # do your field update
```